# what's the means of Volumes field in docker inspect containerId compare with Mounts field?

Tags: docker

docker "Mounts" field can inspect by `docker inspect containerId | grep -A10 '"Mounts"'`.

```
 "Mounts": [
      {
           "Source": "/home/az-user/data/nexus-data-1201/nexus-data",
           "Destination": "/nexus-data",
           "Mode": "",
           "RW": true,
           "Propagation": "rprivate"
      }
 ],
```

That means `/nexus-data` directory in the container map to `/home/az-user/data/nexus-data-1201/nexus-data` directory in the host.

What's means of "Volumes" field means show by `docker inspect containerId | grep -A10 '"Volumes"'`?

In my container, is shows:

```
 "Volumes": {
     "/nexus-data": {}
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the short explanation for volume in docker (and in Linux in general)

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by
>   and used by Docker containers. While bind mounts are dependent on the
>   directory structure of the host machine, volumes are completely
>   managed by Docker

You can read more about volume [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)